# Batch runas user taskkill

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make a batch file the runs runas /user:MyUser "taskkill -f -im chrome.exe", but when i execute it it asks me for my password. I want the batch program to automatically insert the password so it does everything by itself. I know I can just execute as admin, writing just the taskkill -f -im chrome.exe part, but i want to do it in that way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /SaveCred option which will save your credentials the first time you run the command. Subsequent calls will use these cached credentials.

However read this first about the security implications: http://osdir.com/ml/security.ntbugtraq/2003-07/msg00068.html